# Apply step procedure in tidymodels on a per group basis

Tags: r, r-caret, tidymodels

I am looking for a way to apply step functions from the  `tidymodels` package on a per group basis within a `recipe` in general and specifically for the `step_normalize` function.  The code below shows what I would like to do for a simple `recipe`. Thanks

```
library(tidymodels)

data(mtcars)
mtcars$vs=factor(mtcars$vs)
recipe_train = recipe(mpg ~., data =mtcars) %>%
step_normalize(all_predictors()) # perform this for each level of the factor 'vs'
```

Comment: you can split your dataset and do apply the recipe.. I am not very sure if you can include the by group inside the recipe and pass that for training

Comment: can you elaborate if you are trying to obtain a recipe that does that step_normalization by group for downstream model fitting etc

Comment: Yes, I am trying to include it in a general workflow so fitting, predicting on new data etc.  Do you happen to know of a way outside of `tidymodels`?

Comment: The `step_normalize()` function was created with models like regularized regression, nearest neighbors, etc in mind that need to have all predictors on the same scale. We don't currently have support for grouped operations that are learned from training data and then applied to testing data. I would probably suggest doing this outside of tidymodels, using dplyr.

Comment: I was thinking I would probably have to go that route, I will do some research on how to save the scaling information with my model and the overall workflow so I can use on new data. Thanks!